# Show author name from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I want to show in my posting scaffold the name of the author.
I have a posts and users table.

The posts table has an author_id row, that is linking to ID from the users table.

My post model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

And the user model:

```
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
```

How can i show the author name from the users table in a post?

```
**Users format**
ID          integer
name    string

**Posts format**
ID          integer
title   string
content text
author_id   integer
```

This works for the show view:

```
  def show
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@author = User.where(:id => @post.author_id).first
```

end

And this for the index view:

```
  def index
@posts = Post.all
@posts.each do |post|
  @author = User.where(:id => @post.author_id).first 
end
```

end

But the index view doesn't work!

Comment: Are you able to show the structure of both tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.where(....).each do |post|
  post.author
end
```

Comment: I don't know how to precisely use your code, but something like this?
      def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id]) 
        user = User.where(:id => @post.author_id).first 
      end

Comment: @post.author will give you the user you are looking for.

Comment: That's right, any post object will have an author method to get its author.

Comment: @satya I have put this code:  <td><%= @post.author %></td> in my index view, but it shows me an error: undefined method `author' for nil:NilClass

What do i have to put in my controller, to show the author, because i haven't defined an author in my code

Comment: What does the corresponding controller method (action) look like? Are you in a loop, displaying a list of posts?

Comment: It works with the following code in my model:

  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
and in the index view: @message.sender.name

Comment: In the show view, this `@author = User.where(:id => @post.author_id).first` should be simply `@author = @post.author`

Comment: As for the index view, the `@posts.each` block would be in your view, not in your controller.

Answer (score -2):

For index view:

```
@articles.each do |article|
   @author = Author.where(:id => article.author_id).first
end
```